# Building wxWidgets on Windows with MinGW

Tags: windows, mingw, wxwidgets

Building wxWidgets seems impossible. I followed all the steps from the documentation page http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=WxWindowsQuickRef but when I try to compile, the whole command prompt window fills with errors and warnings, then stops, with the last line being `mingw32-make.exe: *** [gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o] Error 1` I suspect it's something to do with MinGW but I don't know.

Comment: I will suggest Visual Studio 2010 for building wxWidgets and then wxWidget applications. This way it will be easier for you to build (simply select project **wx_vc9** from [wx folder]\build\msw and kick back) and VS2010 is a awesome IDE.

Comment: For those still having this issue since all the official guides do not work and/or are overextending.. I created guides for [static](https://deontic-logic.github.io/readme_statdeps_v3.html#build) and [dynamic](https://deontic-logic.github.io/readme_dyndeps_v1.html#build) wxWidgets 3.1.3 libararies. [Here](https://deontic-logic.github.io/readme.html#unix-like-environment-on-windows) I show how to use `.sh` files under Windows, and more. The walkthrough for static libraries ends with an error but builds all the libraries. If you want a full build, do with the makefiles as in the dynamic guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be try this guide, more official

http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW

Answer (score 1):

Alternative is to use precompiled libraries. See [wxPack](http://wxpack.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

you can get precompiled wxWidgets libs and tutorials (building wxWidgets with MinGW) on http://www.philasmicos.de/content/238-wxwidgets_unter_windows_kompilieren.
All tutorials are german but with google translate, it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

MinGW now uses MSys - add MinGW\msys\1.0\bin to your path.
Why not to add symlinks into MinnGW bin folder is a big mystery...